# How to add customer drop down menu in Devexpress Report Designer UI

Tags: devexpress, report-designer

How to add custom dropdown like zoom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom end-user report designer UI as described in the [Create a Custom End-User Report Designer documentation.](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/116704/winforms-reporting/end-user-report-designer/quick-start/create-a-custom-end-user-report-designer)